# React js - ternary adding html block to component - classNames break the block

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, ternary, class-names

My goal is to build comment section that appears and disappears on a toggle click button.

I have the following structure:

set Button state:

```
    const [showButton, toggleShowButton] = useState(false)
```

Button:

```
<button className="comment-button" onClick={() => toggleShowButton(!showButton)}>{showButton ? "Hide comments" : "Show comments"}</button>
```

Conditional html block:

```
                {showButton &&
                    (
                        <div className="article-comment-section">
                            {article.comments && article.comments.map(x =>
                                <CommentCard key={x._id} {...x} />
                            )}

                            {isAuthenticated && <AddComment onCommentSubmit={onCommentSubmit} />}
                        </div>
                    )}
```

The block should appear and disappear on a button click, but it doesn't

I tried to put and an invalid classNames, and then my button works.
But I still want to have my styling on.

Apparently the problem comes from the **classNames**.

How should I apply them so they work?

Comment: Please describe your problem briefly with more information. So you want to show/hide comments here a small example inspired by your snippets I hope this will help 
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lederberg-46t003?file=/src/App.js